# Change Port permanently using WMI and powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

Is there anyway to replicate the terminal services Change Port command permanently, currently when i use said command it has to be done each time i logon, is there a way that this can be achieved permanently without stepping through MMC?

kind regards

stefan

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding right, I think this MS Support article is what you need.

[How to change Terminal Server's listening port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187623)

Comment: I'm trying to remap a serial port from say COM1 to COM74. I know this can be performed through device manager and i know this is a bit of a sketchy thing to do but i need to do it programatically, either through command line or in C++/C#

Comment: Ah, serial ports...  Well, according to this support article, those mappings are not persisted.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186504

Comment: You could make a log on script that did this every time you connect.

Comment: I'm not that fortunate, i'm going to try hooking MMC.. :\ WMI doesn't go this far and the registry is a no go (keys are too sparse) so i'll have a look at what MMC is doing

Answer (score 0):

I have half an answer; anyone with more clues is welcome to add to this. Also, this has only been tested on Windows 7.

There is a value "PortName" in "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\<vendor-specific>\Device Parameters" that contains the port assignment. Change this to the desired COM port. A reboot may be required to make the assignment take, but once it takes, it'll stick.

Unfortunately, the "FriendlyName" value in "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\<vendor-specific>" does not change when you do this, and (at least for my hardware on Win7) only SYSTEM has the rights to change that value, or to change the permissions on that key.

The other option, as mentioned above, is to add the relevant command to the Run section.

(EDIT: Sorry; didn't notice the "registry is a no-go" comment below.)

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the OP's question, it sure answered mine!  Still relevant 11 years later!